# How to automate image tag on ECR using gitlab CI?

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, amazon-ecr

I have an ECR repo.

I'm using a gitlab CI to push and pull an image from that repo. Everytime my CI runs I'm using the same image tag (is fixed in my CI code) like `ECR_IMAGE: app:1.1.8`

My doubt is: Is there a way to automate the tag generation in every CI run?

Example: Everytime my CI runs I want to increment my tag version in 1, like: `1.1.9, 2.0.0, 2.0.1,...`

Comment: In other words, do you want to update the tag in some file after the pipeline has run? If yes, what file? Or should the tag be updated after your pipeline has run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically I used [GitLab Variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html) to do that. I used `CI_COMMIT_SHA` on my CICD yaml to generate the image tag version using the commit hash.